# Is there a way to set hotkeys to locations in StarCraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

I thought that I remembered the ability to assign a hotkey to a location in SC1, but I don't see anything listed in the hotkeys for SC2 for such a thing. I'd like to be able to immediately switch the view to a particular location (like <kbd>Backspace</kbd> does for your base).

I thought I saw something in the key assignments that sounded like it for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> through <kbd>F10</kbd> or something, but when I tried to set them and then use them it looked like they were set to do something else entirely.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you go to options, hotkeys you can assign it to whatever you want. It is called camera-save. By default though some menus take up <kbd>f9</kbd> - <kbd>f12</kbd>, so <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f8</kbd> is the only one that works for camera saving with the default profile. You either need to pick different keys or take the menus off of those hotkeys to get the other ones to work.

Comment: Awesome thanks! So it looks like I had the right option, but why would Blizzard make the defaults unusable?!? Very odd.